# Manifest giving me errors

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

my app was working all fine. I changed the manifest value to "false" for exported , now nothing works. When I run the app , the boolean vale switches to "false" not even "false" !!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cepsa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Cepsa" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cepsa.Citernes"
            android:exported="fasle" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cepsa.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Change it back. If not already, start using version control. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in `android:exported="fasle"` - it should be `android:exported="false"`.

Comment: I guess so, looks like a typo inside it, change "fasle" to "false" on attribute android:exported

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create activity from android studio menu instead of manually to avoid typing errors in `AndroidManifest.xml.`

```
File > New > Activity > Empty Activity
```

or

```
Right click your specific package, and choose New > Activity > Empty Activity
```

or

[See this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqyQM.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please check and mark this answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).